# How to install drive program from hard disk?

Tags: windows-7

I have installed Windows 7 system on my pc. There is no cd or dvd disk drive n my pc, how can I install the drive program?

I build an iso file on another pc from the drive dvd disk with software ultro iso, when I copy it into pc  And enter into PE to load it, click it, I can't make it run.

Comment: Could you please clarify what exactly you’re trying to install? A program that comes on CD/DVD perhaps?

Comment: Run the installer just like any other program you download.  Any archive software can extra the .ISO so you can run the setup routine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are programs that can mount an ISO as a file system, so that even if you dont have a cdrom, you can use the ISO as a virtual cdrom.

Alternately, there are external USB cdroms that work quite well.

I yse this freeware program for cdroms.  You can load it from explorer (right click on an ,iso file etc) or from the command line (i have it as a menu option in Brian Havard's FC/W.

The program is freely downloadable, in 32 and 64 bit versions, and appears with winimage.  Olof writes a number of other interesting utilities worth the look, if ye be a command line junkie.  [I use Windows 2000].

```
ImDisk Virtual Disk Driver for Windows NT/2000/XP/2003.
Version 1.3.0 - (Compiled Jun  7 2010)

Copyright (C) 2004-2009 Olof Lagerkvist.
http://www.ltr-data.se     olof@ltr-data.se
```

Comment: Well, it wouldn’t hurt to name these programs, now would it? ;) For example, there’s [Virtual CloneDrive](http://www.slysoft.com/en/virtual-clonedrive.html) and [DAEMON Tools](http://www.daemon-tools.cc/home). PowerISO and MagicISO also have this as an (optional) feature.

Comment: I use a command-line utility through fcw, which i have not mentioned.  But i edited the main post to include it.

Answer (score -1):

it is my mistake to test all the operation on the win xp ,when changed into win7 , everything is ok.i just simply click on the DVD and copy it onto a file,then click the setup.exe, it work fine for me.The drive program do not support  win xp .

Comment: Good News your not using **Windows XP**!